# expressjs pattern to match the rest of the path

Tags: node.js, express

I'm trying to create an endpoint that contains an actual path that I extract and use as a parameter.  For instance, in the following path:

/myapi/function/this/is/the/path

I want to match "/myapi/function/" to my function, and pass the parameter "this/is/the/path" as the parameter to that function.

If I try this it obviously doesn't work because it only matches the first element of the path:

```
app.get("/myapi/function/:mypath")
```

If I try this it works, but it doesn't show up in `req.params`, I instead have to parse `req.path` which is messy because the logic has to know about the whole path, not just the parameter:

```
app.get("/myapi/function/*")
```

In addition, the use of wildcard routing seems to be [discouraged as bad practice](https://jonathanong.github.io/wildcard-routing-is-an-anti-pattern.html).  I'm not sure I understand what alternative the linked article is trying to suggest, and I'm not using the query as part of a database call nor am I uploading any information.

What's the proper way to do this?

Comment: Any reason you can't use a param string for the value? you would already know on the client what the base path is and what isn't just use that using [bodyparser](https://github.com/expressjs/body-parser) and pass the parameter in then you can use it like `req.body.mypath` just make sure your client sends json data, otherwise if you still want to do what you're doing you'd need to encode the value and send it as a query parameter `app.get("/myapi/function?path={encoded value}"` or something like that and you'll need to decode it on the server since "/" i believe is invalid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use wildcard

```
app.get("/myapi/function/*")
```

And then get your path

```
req.params[0]

// Example
//
// For the route "/myapi/function/this/is/my/path"
// You will get output "this/is/my/path"
```